# 改行毎にawkで区切り、grepで特定の文字列が入っているレコードを抽出したい

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

address.txt から改行毎に区切り、4つのレコードとし、そのうち「合格」という文字列が入っているレコードを抽出するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

以下のコマンドを入力したら全て出力されてしまいます。

```
cat address.txt | awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"} $2=="合格"'
```

**address.txt**

```
東川 雄一
合格
080-1111-1111
〒111-1111
××県××区A町 1-1-1
ABCビル1001


西村 祐二
不合格
080-2222-2222
〒222-2222
××県××市B町 2-22

南山 裕三
合格
080-3333-3333
〒333-3333
××県××市C町 3-3-3
XYZハイツ3号室


北岡 優四
不合格
080-4444-4444
〒444-4444
××県××区D町 4-4-4
```

Answer (score 1):

`RS`(Record Separator) を改行2個(空行)に、`FS`(Field Separator)を改行にするとよろしいかと思います。`ORS` の指定はお好みで。

```sh
awk -F '\n' -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' '$2=="合格"' address.txt
```

**実行結果**

```
東川 雄一
合格
080-1111-1111
〒111-1111
××県××区A町 1-1-1
ABCビル1001

南山 裕三
合格
080-3333-3333
〒333-3333
××県××市C町 3-3-3
XYZハイツ3号室
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました！

ただ、以下のような場合はできませんでした。

----ここから----
hokkaido
        type A
        ABC {
              xxxx
        };
};

yokohama
        type B
};
----ここまで----

なぜでしょうか。。

Comment: "合格"という文字が含まれていませんし、空行も無い様に見受けられますので、データ構造が異なっているから、としか言いようがありません……